# Cucumber rerun failed scenario runs only one scenario

Tags: maven, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, maven-surefire-plugin, cucumber-java

I have a sample project in which, i have used Maven, TestNg and Cucumber. I run my test using testrunner class.

I have created a feature file with two scenarios and both the scenario are failing. I have two testrunner classes with different feature file -- 1. feature file points to all the features, 2. points to only failed scenarios.

When i try to rerun the scenario it runs only one scenario.

1-> features = "src/test/java/com/ag/features" = has all the features
2-> features = @target/rerun.txt = has reference to both the failed features.

Please advise how to make all failed scenarios execute.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to tell cucumber to run the features/scenario lines defined in your rerun file.

cucumber @rerun.txt should be enough (Although in java you may need a little more)

Comment: I just realised i am running code in parallel, due to which both test runners are running at the same time and rerun test runner is not able to find the rerun.txt file. Is there a way to run parallel and failed test cases ?